# bottom position footer is inhibiting normal scroll behavior for main content

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

On this site design http://sproffer.joyatechsolutions.com/page/Pricing, I have positioned the footer at the bottom using some of the helpful information from this tutorial.(http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

However, as you can see in the link - when there is more content, instead of pushing down the content, the footer stays in the same place and the content just goes below it and then creates white space at the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: This will be helpful: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I looked over this site before posting - but am still missing something.  Was hoping that I could get more explicit help.  The other tutorial I used did not have the .push and I'm not exactly sure how to implement it as he describes because my content is served up by a CMS.  I can add divs to the view file overrides, but I'm not clear where that would go given the structure.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your bottom div position is Absolute ( defined in style.css #bottom), just remove it and try if it works.